# Calibrating 3d Accelerometer for 2d Game

Tags: android, accelerometer, libgdx, calibration

I am making a 2d game. The phone is held horizontally and a character moves up/down & left/right to avoid obstacles. The character is controlled by the accelerometer on the phone. Everything works fine if the player doesn't mind `(0,0)` (the point where the character stands still) being when the phone is held perfectly flat. In this scenario it's possible to just read the Y and X values directly and use them to control the character. The accelerometer values are between -10 and 10 (they get multiplied by an acceleration constant to decide the movement speed of the character), `libgdx` is the framework used.

The problem is that having `(0,0)` isn't very comfortable, so the idea is to calibrate it so that 0,0 will be set to the phones position at a specific point in time.

Which brings me to my question, how would I do this? I tried just reading the current X and Y values then subtracting it. The problem with that is that when the phone is held at a 90 degree angle then the X offset value is 10 (which is the max value) so it ends up becoming impossible to move because the value will never go over 10 (`10-10 = 0`). The Z axis has to come into play here somehow, I'm just not sure how.

Thanks for the help, I tried explaining as best as I can, I did try searching for the solution, but I don't even know what the proper term is for what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question, but I am providing the answer here as I couldn't find a good answer for Android or LibGDX anywhere. The code below is based on a solution someone posted for iOS (sorry, I have lost the reference).

You can do this in three parts:

1. Capture a vector representing the neutral direction:

   ```
   Vector3 tiltCalibration = new Vector3( 
                Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX(), 
                Gdx.input.getAccelerometerY(), 
                Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ() );
   ```
2. Transform this vector into a rotation matrix:

   ```
   public void initTiltControls( Vector3 tiltCalibration ) {
       Vector3.tmp.set( 0, 0, 1 );
       Vector3.tmp2.set( tiltCalibration ).nor();
       Quaternion rotateQuaternion = new Quaternion().setFromCross( Vector3.tmp, Vector3.tmp2 );

       Matrix4 m = new Matrix4( Vector3.Zero, rotateQuaternion, new Vector3( 1f, 1f, 1f ) );
       this.calibrationMatrix = m.inv();
   }
   ```
3. Whenever you need inputs from the accelerometer, first run them through the rotation matrix:

   ```
   public void handleAccelerometerInputs( float x, float y, float z ) {

       Vector3.tmp.set( x, y, z );
       Vector3.tmp.mul( this.calibrationMatrix );

       x = Vector3.tmp.x;
       y = Vector3.tmp.y;
       z = Vector3.tmp.z;

       [use x, y and z here]
       ...
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution you can look at the methods:

```
Gdx.input.getAzimuth(), Gdx.input.getPitch(), Gdx.input.getRoll()
```

The downside is that those somehow use the internal compass to give your devices rotation compared to North/South/East/West. I did only test that very shortly so I'm not 100% sure about it though. Might be worth a look.

The more complex method involves some trigonometry, basically you have to calculate the angle the phone is held at from `Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX/Y/Z()`. Must be something like (for rotation along the longer side of the phone):

```
Math.atan(Gdx.input.getAccelerometerX() / Gdx.input.getAccelerometerZ());
```

For both approaches you then store the initial angle and subtract it later on again. You have to watch out for the ranges though, I think `Math.atan(...)` is within `-Pi` and `Pi`.

Hopefully that'll get you started somehow. You might search for "Accelerometer to pitch/roll/rotation" and similar, too.